# Google Pie Chart Disappears When PHP Date Variable Is Before Tomorrow

Tags: php, mysql, sql, google-visualization

I have an SQL query providing me with my Google pie chart figures.  The SQL statement is:

```
$query = "SELECT a.NAME, COUNT(TASK_ID) AS total FROM b_tasks_tag a INNER JOIN b_tasks b ON a.TASK_ID = b.ID WHERE a.NAME LIKE 'Other' AND b.CREATED_DATE BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'";
```

This provides the correct figure and pie chart information when I select the date range **from** any date and **to** tomorrows date.  However when I select **from** any date and **to** any other date than tomorrows date then the pie chart disappears but the table that also displays the information retrieves the correct information.

Is there something within SQL or Google Pie Chart that restricts me viewing figures for date ranges prior to tomorrows date?

Very strange, any clues would be appreciated,

**A form is processed on the same page and the dates are printed out correctly:**

```
<?php
$from = $_POST["from"];
$to = $_POST["to"];
?>
```

The date format is 2013-09-23 which is correctly matched to the database.

**Here is the SQL code:**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("database",$con);
$query = "SELECT a.NAME, COUNT(TASK_ID) AS total FROM b_tasks_tag a INNER JOIN b_tasks b ON a.TASK_ID = b.ID WHERE a.NAME LIKE 'Other' AND b.CREATED_DATE BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$other= $row['total'];

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

**Here is the code for the Pie Chart:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Case Type', 'Number of Cases'],
          ['Other', <?php echo $other ?>]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Breakdown of Case Types',sliceVisibilityThreshold:0
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

I added a time stamp on the form and it basically made the pie chart disappear for any value for the $to before the current time.

Comment: `any other date than tomorrow's date`? your `$to` must always be at least equal and generally GREATER than `$from`. If you have `between '2013-06-01' and '2012-06-01'` you'll get nothing, because the range is backwards.

Comment: Yes, $to is always greater than $from.  I understand I'd get nothing if it wasn't.

Comment: Can you post more code, including $to and $from

Comment: This probably isn't your problem, but your SQL statement is missing the `GROUP BY` clause that should be necessary to handle the grouping the count.  But to the point of the question: there is nothing in SQL or the Google Visualization API that would prevent you from using any valid date for `$to`.  It might help us diagnose your problem if you include the javascript that draws the PieChart (preferably with the data from your database, so we can test it).

Comment: I've updated the post with form, sql and pie chart code.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Can you post what this line `['Other', <?php echo $other ?>]` looks like when you query with `$to` as tomorrow's date and with `$to` as some other date?  Open the page in a browser, view the source code, and paste that line.  I need to see what is being output in order to help you diagnose this problem.